Special value of the Artin--Mazur zeta function in arithmetic dynamics
Let $X$ be a compact manifold and $f: X\rightarrow X$ be a diffeomorphism. Assume that the $k$-fold iterate $f^k: X\rightarrow X$ has finitely many fixed points for all natural numbers $k$. The dynamical zeta function associated to $X$ was introduced by Artin and Mazur and is defined as follows
$$\zeta_f(z):=\text{exp}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k} |\text{Fix}(f^k)|\right).$$
This function converges in a neighborhood of $0$ if $|\text{Fix}(f^k)|$ satisfies a certain growth condition. Also, it is known in certain cases that these functions are rational functions. For instance, consider an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ with integer coefficients and $\mathbb{T}$ be the $n$-dimensional torus $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$. Let $f=f_M: \mathbb{T}\rightarrow \mathbb{T}$ be the function taking $x\mapsto Mx$. Then, the associated Artin--Mazur zeta function is rational and an explicit formula is known, cf. "A note on the dynamical zeta function of general toral endomorphisms"-- Baake, Lau, Paskunas.
On the other hand, the Ihara zeta function of a graph is a special case of such a zeta function. For a graph $X$, let $\zeta_X(z)$ be the Ihara zeta function. Then, setting $r-1$ to denote the Euler characteristic of $X$, it is known that $g(z):=\zeta_X(z)^{-1}$ has a zero of order $r$ at $z=1$ and there is a formula for its leading coefficient given as follows
$$\frac{d^r}{dz^r}g(z)_{|z=1}= (-1)^{r-1} 2^r r! \kappa_X,$$ where $\kappa_X$ is the complexity of $X$. For a reference, see page 78 of "Audrey Terras. Zeta functions of graphs, volume 128 of Cambridge Studies
in Advanced Mathematics.". This invariant $\kappa_X$ is the number of spanning tress of $X$ and can be interpreted as a graph theoretic analogue of the class number, and the formula for the leading coefficient formula is in spirit an analogue of the class number formula.
My question is, for the Artin-Mazur zeta function associated to a dynamical system $f$ on $X$, is there a similar formula, which is related to some invariant associated to the dynamical system which can be interpreted as an analogue of the "class number" (just like in the case for the Ihara zeta function)? I wasn't able to see anything about this in the literature.
Of course, one needs to assume that the Artin-Mazur zeta function is defined at the point $z=1$, which is indeed the case for the toral dynamical systems I described in the second paragraph.
